# Naive python string formatting (common and non-common parts) in big file

Tags: python, string

I have a big file with >50,000 entries like following:

```
259 607 6   262 104 00000   17  0   C   S<->    G   0   Gm  0   G   0   P   C<->    R   0
```

I want to divide each line into two parts:
Part one (common part):

```
259 607 6   262 104 00000   17  0
```

Part two (non common part)

```
C   S<->    G   0   Gm  0   G   0   P   C<->    Rrad    0
```

And print like this:

```
259 607 6   262 104 00000   17  0   C   S<->    
259 607 6   262 104 00000   17  0   P   C<->
```

Any tips?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the format and content.

If it is fixed width:

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        common=line[:36]
        noncommon=line[36:]
        part1=noncommon[:8]
        part2=noncommon[36:44]
        print(common+part1)
        print(common+part2)
```

If it is field based:

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields=line.split()
        common=fields[:8]
        part1=fields[8:10]
        part2=fields[16:18]
        print(common+part1, sep=' ')
        print(common+part2, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Thanks, The problem is the line can be of different lengths with the same format. So subsetting is not really useful here where the length of the lines is not known.